# using do/while loops I need to take input from the user then output it backwards java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
class DoWhilePrac2 {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String word1;            
    do {
        System.out.println ("Please enter a series of words, please type . to exit");
        word1 = br.readLine ();            
    }
        while (!word1.equalsIgnoreCase ("."));        
       System.out.println(word1);
    }
}
```

I have an assignment for school, using a do/while loop, create a program which will have the user enter a series of words (pressing ‘.’ to exit). Then,
output the sentence, which was creating by concatenating all of
the words together. I need help with it.

Comment: Please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the documentation in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  In particular, you should read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what sorts of questions are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here at SO.  Generally asking for open-ended help is off-topic here, since we don't know what you're actually stuck on unless you tell us.

Comment: For a more in-depth explanation, please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `StringBuilder` to add all the string input from user, then later you can convert it back to string. This way it's more efficient. Below is the code,

```
public static String printSentence() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String word = "";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a series of words, type . to exit");
        builder = builder.append(word);
        word = reader.readLine();
    } while (!word.equals("."));

    return builder.toString();
}
```